# Can automator create symlinks but skip existing files?

Tags: bash, automator, symlink

Today I discovered the awesome [Create Symlinks action from JuneCloud](http://junecloud.com/software/mac/junecloud-automator-actions.html#save-for-web).  It works great, but creates duplicate files (appending a number to each one) for any symlink that already exists in the final location.  I want it to just ignore those files and keep on trucking.

I tried using a shell script `ln -s` but that just plain fails with a `The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error.` message after hitting a file that already exists.

Is there a way to create a symlink but SKIP existing files?  I know I can us `-f` to overwrite but I'd rather just skip.  How can this be done either in Automator or shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can do it easily in the shell script. The `-h` flag fits the bill, as described (sort of) on the [ln man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ln.1.html). So instead of doing `ln -s`, do `ln -sh`.

Here's an example. Say you wanted to make a symbolic link of each of your downloads, which would exist on your Desktop, but you already have some symbolic links there. Then you could do this:

```
cd Downloads
for f in *; do ln -sh ~/Downloads/"$f" ~/Desktop; done;
```

For any files that you have that you already have symbolic links for, the command will print out:

```
    ln: /Users/******/Desktop/FlashPlayer.dmg: File exists
```

The command does this printing after running so it does not throw any errors nor require any additional inputs.

Comment: OHH!  Well damn.  I read the man (believe it or not!  lol) but where it says that -h causes ln to "not follow" the link if it exists, I didn't take that to mean "skip and keep going".  Unfortunately it's not working, Automator still barfs because "file exists".  =(

Comment: @JonathanvanClute Yeah it's confusing

Comment: Any idea why Automator still doesn't like it?

Comment: I don't know, except you might want to try running the script by itself (w/o Automator) and making sure it works like that.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm specifically passing a list of files into the script, which is why I'm using automator in the first place.  I know slightly more than nothing about shell scripting so building the entire thing myself that way is out of the question.  I'd love to avoid shell entirely if I could but it seems Automator is strangely lacking in certain areas.

Comment: Holy crap I fixed it!  Thanks to this web page:  http://tewha.net/2012/07/make-a-symbolic-link-from-finder/ - I happened to notice a small detail in their version of the ln script - a `shift;` after the ln command.  Just for the hell of it I put it in and voila - no errors at all, and the script performs exactly as I had hoped it would.  Eureka!  =)